# How To Change Two Date Formats in the Same Sheet in Excel

Tags: excel

I am currently collecting the birthdays of all users to enter into a single excel file the users have filled their DOB in **DD/MM/YYYY** order as shown in the image 1 below on excel online when I open the excel the number formats are switched to **MM/DD/YYYY** for some of the dates other dates which are above 12 are staying the same the second picture shows the change I have tried text to column feature still no help and tried and fiddled around with date formats still no use need some help ....

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDhuI.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsORe.png)

any way to fix it ok if this can be fixed by excel commands or anyway else there are more than 10k data so manual editing is out the question

Comment: What database was used for data entry?  Are the dates correct in that original database? Are the dates in Excel online, that have the correct format, text strings or real dates?

Comment: Its actually collected into one excel users have typed their data as DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: some dates are correct like dates above 12 they dont seem to change days below 12 are switching places month becomes date date becomes month

Comment: on the online sheet the date appears correctly when i download it to Excel they seem to change

Comment: In the online sheet, in some cell in row 2 (or whatever the first row of data is), enter the formula `=isnumber(F2)` and fill down. What do you see?  All TRUE, all FALSE, or a mix? (assuming column F is the column of user entered dates)

Comment: i entered the formula its shown as a mix true and false

Comment: the Dates which don't change are shown as "FALSE" and the dates which Switch Are Shown As "TRUE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your users have entered their dates as `DD/MM/YYYY`, but Excel online expected `MM/DD/YYYY`.  Hence dates where `D>12` were transformed to a text string; and where `D<=12` were interpreted as `MDY`.

***Formula changed as dates were entered `DMY` and not `DDMMYYYY`***

Best would be for users to enter their dates using a userform or date picker where you have control over what is entered.

You can try the following to transform the dates into "real dates":

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F2),DATE(YEAR(F2),DAY(F2),MONTH(F2)),
LET(x,SUBSTITUTE(F2,"/",REPT(" ",99)),dmy,--TRIM(MID(x,{1,99,198},99)), DATE(INDEX(dmy,3),INDEX(dmy,2),INDEX(dmy,1))))
```

and fill down

Comment: the real dates are coming from the formula after i fill down and convert the "real dates" using format cells they are showing wrong dates should i need to change any thing

Comment: @San10deep If the dates are not being converted correctly, then I've misunderstood something you wrote.  Did you convert the dates in the ONLINE version of Excel? If not, try it there.

Comment: 9th of september is shown as 01st of september

Comment: @San10deep From what you've written, that makes no sense to me. Try the conversion in the online Excel. If that doesn't work, I'd need access to an online Excel that demonstrates the problem -- perhaps remove the information in the columns that don't show a date for confidentiality purposes.

Comment: @San10deep Never mind, I see the problem.  Your users did **NOT** use the format `DD/MM/YYYY`.  Rather they used the format `D/M/Y`.  That requires a different formula.

Comment: @San10deep See edited response.  This should work in Excel online.

Comment: it worked userform or date picker are these options from excel or from VB

Comment: @San10deep vba. Not sure how you would add that on Excel online